# Prevent Screen Light TURN OFF | Disable Sleep Mode in Watch Interface

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch, watch

In Apple Watch Interface, After some time screen light Turned Off. I want to prevent screen light Turn off. I have implemented timer like functionality, That will display objects and continuous change it (Like Photo Slider Album). It's long-running task 160-240 seconds.

Everything working fine BUT screen light turn off After some time. Is there any way to continues to Activate Watch Screen light?

**Simply, I want to Turn ON watch screen light 160-250 seconds anyhow...**

Answer (score 1):

The timeout is a system limitation to conserve battery life, so it is not possible for a developer to prevent the Apple Watch display from entering a sleep state.

Comment: Is there any idea How Apple Watch Breathe App prevent it? It's continuous turn on screen light up to breathing session. I want to turn on watch interface light 160-180 seconds.

Comment: Since it's Apple's own app, they must have chosen not to extend that capability to third-party developers. If you file a suggestion to them at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com then maybe the ability will be added in the future.

Comment: @AustinConlon would you know any updates on this feature? I think I might use one of my Apple code-review ticket or use feedbackassistant on this, because my app (in development) would benefit from this feature, and I think it's sad that Apple doesn't provide the API for third-party developers.